# Continued fraction [1; 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4....]

Tags: continued-fractions

Is the continued fraction $\left[1;2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4\dots\right]$, where every positive integer $n$ is repeated $n$ times in order starting at $1$, a known value? What properties does it have? I've been unable to find any reference to this number anywhere (with an admittedly limited search).

The only observation I've been able to make is that its slightly less than $\sqrt2$, which makes sense as the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt2$ is $[1;\bar2]$, and the above series diverges from that one quite slowly (and the elements of the series have less influnce over the final value the later into the series they are).

Comment: We need a continued fractions equivalent of OEIS.

Comment: @J.G. You could argue *every* integer sequence can be a continued fraction... ([related OEIS sequence btw](https://oeis.org/A002024))

Comment: Yeah, we probably just need the OEIS to add continued fraction information. I already checked they didn't for that particular sequence.

Comment: Numerical value is $$1.410804373305871560545114955738797442117871310429336631975\cdots$$ Wolfram Alpha's output of possible closed forms does not indicate something special about this number. Apart from its curious continued fraction representation, it seems to be just some (probably transcendental) real number.

Comment: $\frac{691+246 \pi +388 \pi ^2}{122+125 \pi +328 \pi ^2}$ is in error of $2.61\times 10^{-19}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici How did you come up with this?

Comment: @user2661923 Small program of mine using a bunch of heuristics

Comment: @hakr14 Using the lindep-function of PARI/GP , you can find such approximations as the one given by Claude : If $x$ is the number to be approximated and you use the base , lets say , $1,\pi,\pi^2$ , then we have $\frac{A+B\pi+C\pi^2}{D+E\pi+F\pi^2} \approx x$ , so $A+B\pi+C\pi^2-Dx-E\pi x-F\pi^2x \approx 0$ , so "lindep([1,Pi,Pi^2,-x,-x * Pi,-x * Pi^2],k)" gives the coefficients you need. $k$ determines the accuracy, it can as well be omitted.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Why is that approximation surprising? You have 18 digits in that expression, so we *expect* to be able to get ≈18 digits of accuracy.. We just need to try a few to find one. No?